# CSS not working in Safari - OK in Chrome, Firefox, windows machine

Tags: macos, safari

safari working perfectly in windows machine but safari not accepting css in mac system . . |
1-search box
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBNkI.png)